# Does anyone know what this transformer block is for?

Tags: transformer

I have just moved into a new flat and mounted on the wall outside the bathroom is a white box. Inside the white box is a transformer and a circuit board. Can anyone help me identify what the purpose of this is?

[image: Mystery box]

Many thanks

Comment: Extract fan off-delay timer?

Comment: Is it the doorbell?

Comment: I'm with Transistor on this one. Big reisstor and setting twiddle-pot on the board, LS (live switched) L and N on the block, all point to a fan timer.

Comment: Yes that would make sense that it's the extractor fan. The LED on the left comes on when I turn the bathroom light on. Thanks for solving this :)

Comment: Im curious, whats the LS Terminal for?

Comment: It's the power supply for the hidden camera.

Comment: It could be for anything. I would trace the wires leaving the box and see where they go. 1 pair is the power supply (brown and black)

Comment: It's for changing the voltage from one level to another.

Comment: Does your bathroom have a shaver outlet?  Those are 110V and require a transformer.

Comment: Alao does your flat have a doorbell and how does it work? Did you unplug anything from those plugs mid-PCB? That box has a cover, did you remove that or was it missing before?